# Read field as string, even if it is an integer or a float

Tags: ruby, string, csv

I need to assign some object that can be strings, integers or floats, but I always need them stored as strings.

```
a = myvar.to_s
```

This solution works most of the times, but when for example myvar is "7.50", "a" will be "7.5"

My need is to have a to have the same number of decimals as the original one. Is there a way to tell ruby that the variable I'm reading will be a string, no matter what it looks like.

EDIT: I'm importing data from a csv file, I'm looking for a way to tell ruby that everything  it will read will be a string, no matter if it looks like an integer or a float.
For example I can have values like "7", "5.5000", "5.5" etc.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what is it that you're asking.

Comment: Could you add more details about your data source, and how you end up with a `Float` in the first place? Any solution is likely to need to take account of the (de-)serialisation layer. It is likely to get complicated if you expect to modify values yet keep same format, you will need something that is aware of correct format for each field (including number of significant digits for numerics)

Comment: You can't specify the number of digits for floats: `myvar = 7.50 #=> 7.5`

Comment: @NeilSlater, I edited the question trying to make it more clear

Comment: Using Ruby 2.0 and the CSV.foreach(file.csv) method I am only able to parse data as stings (and thus I am not having the problem you are describing). No numbers are converted to floats or ints. How is your csv formated? How do you parse the data using the CSV.foreach function?

Comment: You are asking a question stating a problem that we can't reproduce on our own means. It's up to you, the OP, to post a question containing the code and sample data that reproduces the problem, and, at that point we can try to help. As is, this question makes little sense and, because we can't reproduce the problem you're seeing, we can't help fix it. Please read http://sscce.org/ and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist to create a question that helps us help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make sure that you don't use any [CSV converters](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#Converters) in the first place. So for example, instead of:

```
CSV.parse_line("foo,7,5.5000,5.5", converters: :numeric)
#=> ["foo", 7, 5.5, 5.5]
```

You would just use:

```
CSV.parse_line("foo,7,5.5000,5.5")
#=> ["foo", "7", "5.5000", "5.5"]
```

**Full example:**

```
require 'csv'
require 'tempfile'

file = Tempfile.new(['foo', '.csv'])
file << "7.50"
file.close

CSV.foreach(file.path) do |row|
  p row[0]
  p row[0].class
end
```

**Output**:

```
"7.50"
String
```

Tested in Ruby 1.8.7, 1.9.3 and 2.0.0, all return `"7.50"`

Comment: I'm just using CSV.foreach(foo) do |row| ---- does it make a difference?

Comment: No, it takes the same options hash.

Comment: If the value in the csv is "7.50" row[0] is 7.5 and row[0].class is float. How can I tell it to read row[0] as a string?

Comment: @TopperH I cannot reproduce this, see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Precision for float in Ruby is not adjustable individually. In other words, there is no notion of precision set for each float. Assuming that you are trying to convert a float into a string, your description `the same number of decimals as the original one` does not make sense because there is no such thing as `the number of decimals of the original float`.

If you want to specify a particular precision, you can only do that at the moment or after a float is converted to string.

Comment: There is *possibly* such a thing as "the number of decimals of the original **serialised** float", depending on response from OP.

Comment: @NeilSlater I don't know what you mean by `serialised float`. If you mean a string, then that does not contradict with what I wrote.

Comment: Yes, I mean the string representation of the float, where I am presuming the OP has obtained data, and is referring as "original". I agree your post is correct on a literal reading of the question, so this is not a contradiction, just a very likely complication.